# Call method of dynamic key

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar

This is my data object:

```
registration: {
        step1: {
          project: '',
        },
        step2: {
          adres: '',
          facade: '',
          floor: '',
        },
      },
```

I am trying to validate the user inputs with a single function for each step like this:

```
validateStep(stepNumber) { 
    const self = this; 
    const step = step${stepNumber}; 
    console.log(step); 
    this.$v.registration[${step}].touch(); 
    if (this.$v.registration[${step}].$error) { 
      this.$q.notify('Controleer aub de velden opnieuw'); 
      return; 
    } 

    self.$refs.stepper.next();
}
```

But this gives this error:

> TypeError: this.$v.registration["".concat(...)].touch is not a
>   function

I also tried it like this:

```
validateStep(stepNumber) {
      const self = this;
      const step = `step${stepNumber}`;
      console.log(this.$v.registration[step]); //this prints the correct object
      const currentStep = this.$v.registration[step];
      currentStep.touch();

      if (currentStep.$error) {
        this.$q.notify('Controleer aub de velden opnieuw');
        return;
      }
      self.$refs.stepper.next();
    },
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the `touch` method you are trying to access? This is not a standard JavaScript object method.

Comment: It is a method from vuelidate (it's a vue app in quasar)

https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/#sub-package-content

Comment: Okay, I'm not a Vue dev but looking at the documentation you've shared. I can't see any reference to `touch` method, only a `$touch` method. Seems obvious but could this be your issue?

Comment: Sometimes the most obvious things are the hardest to spot. You are indeed correct! this fixed it. Now how can I select your comment as the accepted answer?

Comment: Ha, no worries, glad it worked. I'll submit that as an answer separately for you to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vuelidate method should be `$touch` instead of `touch`.